# Git clean exclude nested sub directory

Tags: git

I'am having trouble with git clean and exclude options for nested dirs.

I would like to clean all uncommitted files from repo excluding `vendor/bundle` dir.
My test repo loks like:

```
debugg-dir/
  .git/
  file.txt
  not-commited-file
  not-commited-folder
      another-not-commited-file
  vendor/
    bundle/
      another-not-commited-file
```

Reproduce test repo with:

```
git init debugg-dir && cd debugg-dir
touch file.txt && g add . && git commit -m "Commit" 
mkdir -p not-commited-folder && touch not-commited-folder/another-not-commited-file
mkdir -p vendor/bundle && touch vendor/bundle/another-not-commited-file && touch not-commited-file
```

Git clean command:

```
git clean -d -x -n -e vendor/bundle
```

After clean expected to have:

```
debugg-dir/
  .git/
  file.txt
  vendor/
    bundle/
      another-not-commited-file
```

Is there any proper way to exclude nested dir from git clean command?

**# EDIT:**

**Explanation:**

There is no "clean" solution for this situation.
Git clean excludes dirs with `git clean -d -x -n -e dir_name` but this doesn't work with nested dirs.
Is this bug in git or there is some good reason for that? More info why this doesnt work you can find [in source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a25014bc4cef56712f7d005d7b76070d0270f454/dir.c#L404). Long story short, exclude pattern only works for strings till first '/' in pattern.

**My solution:**

```
cd vendor && git clean -dxf -e bundle && cd ..
git clean -dxf -e vendor
```

With this i  managed to only keep nested dir and it's contents.

Comment: Consider removing personal aliases to allow anyone to reproduce the example: `g a . && git ci -m "Commit"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per `git clean --help`

> git-clean - Remove untracked files from the working tree

If you add to this Floyd Pink's explanation about `-d` (shortly, the option allows to remove also untracked directories and not just files), then that is why you get `vendor` removed as well.
Now, <s>supposedly you want to remove only `not-commited-file` (so, neither any untracked directory nor `another-not-commited-file`)</s> I think you should `git clean` interactive mode, <s>so</s>

```
git clean -i
```

which will ask you what to do for each untracked file (only files, add `-d` if you want to asked for directory too).
**EDIT** after OP's question editing: you want to remove directories too, so run

```
git clean -i -d
```

**EDIT 2**: since the meaning of `-e` was not clear to me from the manual, I googled it and found [this](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-clean-exclude-broken-td6721857.html). I suggest reading the conversation since it explains the real meaning of `-e` which is not how the OP intended it (or can be understood from the manual)

**EDIT 3**, more about `-e` switch. Following the link I found in *edit 2*, I decided to try it out. Here the result, which I hope will help you to understand `-e`.
Content of `.gitignore`, so I don't commit temporary files:

```
*.tmp
```

I issued the commands:

```
echo "Temporary file" > sample.tmp
git st //which of course shows *nothing to commit, working directory clean*
git clean -fX -e \!sample.tmp
```

The result is that ALL files with tmp extension are deleted (due to `-X`) BUT `sample.tmp`. So, in conclusion, what `-e` really does, in my understanding and please correct me if in the I am wrong, is NOT to exclude patterns from the cleaning process but

> to exclude patterns from the rule of cleaning (in my case the rule was to remove ALL .tmp files, from which I manually excluded sample.tmp).

Comment: `git clean` does not have an interactive mode. Does it?

Comment: it has. Just try it out (or read `git clean --help`). Disclaimer: on my laptop, `git --version` shows `git version 1.8.5`, it possibly does not exist in earlier versions

Comment: Could not see it [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html), but the more official one [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) does have an `-i` switch.

Comment: @FloydPink, I honestly and very often find git `--help` switch really clear and, obviously, complete. I suggest to use it as first source of reference and then use other sources for examples or clarifications. Then, of course, there are exceptions (like `-e`, see EDIT 2) and use cases which can be better found and understood from web (http://git-scm.com/ is usually amazing, lot of examples, use cases, special cases, ...)

Comment: Thank you. I do use `--help` a lot, but am on Windows now and it looks like I haven't updated git in quite some time. I was on `v1.8.1` and it is already `v1.8.5` now. And from [here](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt) I realize that `git clean` "learned" interactive mode in `v1.8.4`. Thanks to you I learnt this today. :)

Comment: And, as you can guess from my first comment, I didn't know it was such a new feature :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `vendor` is an untracked directory and you are using the option `- d`.

As [the manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html) says:

> -d
>
> > Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. If an untracked directory is managed by a different git repository, it is not removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to remove such a directory.

I could get the required output using this command:

```
git clean -x -n
```

Does that work in the real scenario? If it doesn't, you might want to commit some other file within `vendor/bundle` and then see.

Comment: What is situation when there is untracked directory eg. in root of project, how to clean that too?

Comment: Do you want to explore the option `-X` Instead of `-x`? This allows to clean only those files that are indicated in `.gitignore` - [Read more](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html)

Comment: I can't rely on .gitignore, i need more generic solution. 
Updated question, now is more realistic.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to clean up my git repos while excluding the `venv/` directory and sub-directory:

```
git clean -nXd -e \!venv -e \!venv/**
```

For your case, the first exclusion will be enough:

```
git clean -nXd -e \!vendor
```

The second exclusion `\!venv/**` are for other rules in .gitignore that may apply to file or folder inside vendor. Ex:

```
.gitignore    
*.log

vendor/
  bundle/
    another-not-commited-file.log
```

Comment: The negator (`!`) does not do anything for `-e`. The first command excludes`venv` only because you use `-X` (capital X rather than small x) which means that you don't have `venv` in your `.gitignore`. Also note that `**` is interpreted by the shell, not by git.

Answer (score -1):

Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) makes **`git clean`** more robust when it comes to nested Git *repositories* (not just folders)

See [commit 69f272b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69f272b922df153c86db520bf9b6018a9808c2a6) (01 Oct 2019), and [commit 902b90c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/902b90cf42bc3c05f9fd124edac42ef1fc4ffafa), [commit ca8b539](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca8b5390db928014af9aadc73c876198501bfb35), [commit 09487f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09487f2cbad36d5da42e204c9e0d201e8607acb8), [commit e86bbcf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e86bbcf987faad8e487beb814351a404fa80957f), [commit 3aca580](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3aca58045f4fa4ad25042f0850706b1d00fd77f1), [commit 29b577b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29b577b96082d87b7237fdc57bf95cfe0914c53d), [commit 89a1f4a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89a1f4aaf7650288b976c6022b2c5854950d52c6), [commit a3d89d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3d89d8f7681c61c7fe04a0c01c7310a375f3d0e), [commit 404ebce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/404ebceda01c5af68926c3ee78934cd95bda2602), [commit a5e916c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a5e916c7453bc022cb86d7f8528952ccda6a81ce), [commit bbbb6b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbbb6b0b898d0a03175a902524fb3a371fbd5b3f), [commit 7541cc5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7541cc530239b14edacfa5750f8ab3a8a62dc545) (17 Sep 2019) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit aafb754](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aafb75452b2e9b3f17db3a07e9ed1cf77fdce693), 11 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### `clean`: avoid removing untracked files in a nested Git repository
>
> Users expect files in a nested git repository to be left alone unless sufficiently forced (with two `-f`'s).
>
> Unfortunately, in certain circumstances, git would delete both tracked (and possibly dirty) files and untracked files within a nested repository.
>
> To explain how this happens, let's contrast a couple cases.
>
> First, take the following example setup (which assumes we are already within a git repo):

```
git init nested
cd nested
>tracked
git add tracked
git commit -m init
>untracked
cd ..
```

> In this setup, everything works as expected; running '`git clean -fd`' will result in `fill_directory()` returning the following paths:

```
nested/
nested/tracked
nested/untracked
```

> and then `correct_untracked_entries()` would notice this can be compressed to:

```
nested/
```

> and then since "`nested/`" is a directory, we would call `remove_dirs("nested/", ...)`, which would check `is_nonbare_repository_dir()` and then decide to skip it.
>
> However, if someone also creates an ignored file:

```
>nested/ignored
```

> then running '`git clean -fd`' would result in `fill_directory()` returning
>   the same paths:

```
nested/
nested/tracked
nested/untracked
```

> but `correct_untracked_entries()` will notice that we had ignored entries
>   under nested/ and thus simplify this list to

```
nested/tracked
nested/untracked
```

> Since these are not directories, we do not `call remove_dirs()` which was the only place that had the `is_nonbare_repository_dir()` safety check -- resulting in us deleting both the untracked file and the tracked (and possibly dirty) file.
>
> One possible fix for this issue would be walking the parent directories of each path and checking if they represent nonbare repositories, but that would be wasteful.
>   Even if we added caching of some sort, it's still a waste because we should have been able to check that "nested/" represented a nonbare repository before even descending into it in the first place.
>   Add a `DIR_SKIP_NESTED_GIT` flag to `dir_struct.flags` and use it to prevent `fill_directory()` and friends from descending into nested git repos.
>
> With this change, we also modify two regression tests added in [commit 91479b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/91479b9c72f1ffb13493736954149a34fddaf3aa) ("`t7300`: add tests to document behavior of clean and nested git", 2015-06-15, Git v2.6.0-rc0).
>   That commit, nor its series, nor the six previous iterations of that series on the mailing list discussed why those tests coded the expectation they did.
>   In fact, it appears their purpose was simply to test *existing* behavior to make sure that the performance changes didn't change the behavior.
>   However, these two tests directly contradicted the manpage's claims that two `-f`'s were required to delete files/directories under a nested git repository.
>   While one could argue that the user gave an explicit path which matched files/directories that were within a nested repository, there's a slippery slope that becomes very difficult for users to understand once you go down that route (e.g. what if they specified "`git clean -f -d '*.c'`"?)
>   It would also be hard to explain what the exact behavior was; avoid such problems by making it really simple.
>
> Finally, there are still a couple bugs with `-ffd` not cleaning out enough (e.g.  missing the nested `.git`) and with `-ffdX` possibly cleaning out the wrong files (paying attention to outer `.gitignore` instead of inner).
>   This patch does not address these cases at all (and does not change the behavior relative to those flags), it only fixes the handling when given a single `-f`.
>   See [this thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/20190905212043.GC32087@szeder.dev/) for more discussion of the `-ffd[X?]` bugs.

---

With Git 2.25.1 (Feb. 2020), a corner case bugs in "`git clean`" that stems from a (necessarily for performance reasons) awkward calling convention in the directory enumeration API has been corrected.

See [commit 0cbb605](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cbb60574e741e8255ba457606c4c90898cfc755), [commit ad6f215](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad6f2157f951dc2ffeb7a01f090686f0bbb06f7a) (16 Jan 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 2270533](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22705334b91275563c48f38a52d1643a14e5507b) (16 Jan 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit f365bf4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f365bf40a073624b96651c9f731da4bd7d0114f7) (16 Jan 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7ab963e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ab963e1225ac8dc378142e8632b4dc94c25b351), 05 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`dir`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22705334b91275563c48f38a52d1643a14e5507b): `treat_leading_path()` and `read_directory_recursive()`, round 2
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
>
> I was going to title this "`dir`: more synchronizing of `treat_leading_path()` and `read_directory_recursive()`", a nod to [commit 777b42034764](https://github.com/git/git/commit/777b420347649f26022bb1a4bf7afe7c4fe0b090) ("`dir`: synchronize `treat_leading_path()` and `read_directory_recursive()`", 2019-12-19, Git v2.25.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2189a721cc08b78b63853b8aa825dc828e835cf)), but the title was too long.
>
> Anyway, first the backstory...
>
> `fill_directory()` has always had a slightly error-prone interface: it returns a subset of paths which *might* match the specified pathspec; it was intended to prune away some paths which didn't match the specified pathspec and keep at least all the ones that did match it.
>
> Given this interface, callers were responsible to post-process the results and check whether each actually matched the pathspec.
>
> [`builtin/clean.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/22705334b91275563c48f38a52d1643a14e5507b/builtin/clean.c) did this.
>
> It would first prune out duplicates (e.g. if "`dir`" was returned as well as all files under "`dir/`", then it would simplify this to just "`dir`"), and after pruning duplicates it would compare the remaining paths to the specified pathspec(s).
>
> This post-processing itself could run into problems, though, as noted in [commit 404ebceda01c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/404ebceda01c5af68926c3ee78934cd95bda2602) ("`dir`: also check directories for matching pathspecs", 2019-09-17, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aafb75452b2e9b3f17db3a07e9ed1cf77fdce693) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468)):
>
> > For the case of `git clean` and a set of pathspecs of "`dir/file`" and "`more`", this caused a problem because we'd end up with dir entries for both:  "`dir`" and "`dir/file`"
> >     Then `correct_untracked_entries()` would try to helpfully prune duplicates for us by removing "`dir/file`" since it's under "`dir`", leaving us with "`dir`".
> >     Since the original pathspec only had "`dir/file`", the only entry left doesn't match and leaves nothing to be removed.
> >     (Note that if only one pathspec was specified, e.g. only "`dir/file`", then the `common_prefix_len optimizations` in `fill_directory` would cause us to bypass this problem, making it appear in simple tests that we could correctly remove manually specified pathspecs.)
>
> That commit fixed the issue -- when multiple pathspecs were specified -- by making sure `fill_directory()` wouldn't return both "`dir`" and "`dir/file`" outside the `common_prefix_len` optimization path.
>
> This is where it starts to get fun.
>
> In [commit b9670c1f5e6b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9670c1f5e6b98837c489a03ac0d343d30e08505) ("`dir`: fix checks on common prefix directory", 2019-12-19, Git v2.25.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2189a721cc08b78b63853b8aa825dc828e835cf)), we noticed that the `common_prefix_len` wasn't doing appropriate checks and letting all kinds of stuff through, resulting in recursing into .git/ directories and other craziness.
>
> So it started locking down and doing checks on pathnames within that code path.
>
> That continued with [commit 777b42034764](https://github.com/git/git/commit/777b420347649f26022bb1a4bf7afe7c4fe0b090) ("`dir`: synchronize `treat_leading_path()` and `read_directory_recursive()`", 2019-12-19, Git v2.25.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2189a721cc08b78b63853b8aa825dc828e835cf)), which noted the following:
>
> > Our optimization to avoid calling into `read_directory_recursive()` when all pathspecs have a common leading directory mean that we need to match the logic that `read_directory_recursive()` would use if we had just called it from the root.
> >     Since it does more than call `treat_path()`, we need to copy that same logic.
>
> ...and then it more forcefully addressed the issue with this wonderfully ironic statement:
>
> > Needing to duplicate logic like this means it is guaranteed someonewill eventually need to make further changes and forget to update both locations.
> >     It is tempting to just nuke the `leading_directory` special casing to avoid such bugs and simplify the code, but `unpack_trees`' `verify_clean_subdirectory()` also calls `read_directory()` and does so with a non-empty leading path, so I'm hesitant to try to restructure further.
> >     Add obnoxious warnings to `treat_leading_path()` and `read_directory_recursive()` to try to warn people of such problems.
>
> You would think that with such a strongly worded description, that its author would have actually ensured that the logic in `treat_leading_path()` and `read_directory_recursive()` did actually match and that *everything* that was needed had at least been copied over at the time that this paragraph was written.
>
> But you'd be wrong, I messed it up by missing part of the logic.